# Unreal Engine access violation crashes using third party library code

Tags: c++, crash, ros, unreal-engine4

Some background information first.

I'm currently trying to write a c++ class that can parse a file and generate a tree structure from it that I will be able to use for Inverse Kinematics. To do this I'm making use of some ROS libraries that are able to incorporate the functionality that I need, namely urdf and kdl.

I've managed to link the libraries into the build system through following the instructions here https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Linking_Static_Libraries_Using_The_Build_System

My class can now recognize the structures that I want to make use of, and compiles successfully, but unfortunately Unreal crashes when I try to stop it running,

The code below is from my c++ file, and the issue seems to revolve around garbage collection of my urdf model, as it manages to successfully parse the file only to crash on stopping.

```
    #include "AIKTester.h"
    #include "Runtime/Core/Public/Misc/Paths.h"
    #include "Runtime/Core/Public/HAL/FileManager.h"
    #include <string>

    // Sets default values
    AAIKTester::AAIKTester()
    {
        // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
        PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    }

    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    void AAIKTester::BeginPlay()
    {
        Super::BeginPlay();
        urdfParser();
    }

    // Called every frame
    void AAIKTester::Tick(float DeltaTime)
    {
        Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

    }

    bool AAIKTester::urdfParser()
    {
        // Grab relative project path for file system and convert to string
        FString RelativeProjPath = FPaths::ProjectDir();
        std::string ProjPath(TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*RelativeProjPath));

        // Try parse urdf file into model using relative project path and urdf file location
        if (!my_model.initFile(ProjPath + "Source/Project/robot.urdf")) {
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Failed to parse urdf file"));
            return false;
        }
        else {
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Parsed the urdf file"));
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And here is the included header file:

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "../../ThirdParty/ROS2/Includes/urdf/model.h"
#include "../../ThirdParty/ROS2/Includes/kdl/tree.hpp"
#include "../../ThirdParty/ROS2/Includes/kdl_parser/kdl_parser.hpp"
#include "AIKTester.generated.h"


UCLASS()
class PROJECT_API AAIKTester : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AAIKTester();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    urdf::Model my_model;
    bool urdfParser();
};
```

I've tried to get my head around the call stack, but unfortunately I can't get any clarity about how to solve this problem. The error code and call stack seem to change every other time running it, most recently displaying:

Exception thrown at 0x00007FF80FEE731E (nvwgf2umx.dll) in UE4Editor.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.